# convert the inverse of sum of two hermitian matrices into sum of two or more matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I want to convert the inverse of sum of two hermitian matrices into sum of two or more matrices. I mean I want to simplify the bellow equation in a way that not to have inverse of sum of matrices any more. In the bellow equation $B$ is a $L\times L$ diagonal matrix with real elements on the diagonal and $A$ is a $N\times L$ matrix.

$(A^HA+B^{-2})^{-1}$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write
$$
(B^{-2} + A^HA)^{-1} = 
(B^{-1})^{-1}(I + B A^HA B)^{-1}(B^{-1})^{-1} =
B(I + B A^HA B)^{-1}B
$$
So now, it suffices to calculate $(I + B A^HA B)^{-1}$.  If you'd prefer an infinite sum, we can write (if the entries of $B$ are sufficiently small)
$$
(I + B A^HA B)^{-1} = I - B A^HA B + (B A^HA B)^2 - (B A^HA B)^3 + \cdots
$$
Note also that $I + B A^HA B$ is Hermitian.